# NODE-red docker not recognizing npm installations

Tags: postgresql, docker, node-red

I am using docker to run `node-red` and `postgresql` on a raspberry pi. My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
services:
  nodered:
    build: .
    image: "nodered/node-red:latest"
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - mqtt
  mqtt:
    image: "eclipse-mosquitto:latest"
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=baeldung
      - POSTGRES_USER=baeldung
```

All docker containers are working.

I have the [node-red-contrib-postgresql](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-postgresql) package installed globally on the raspberry pi. However, node-red does not recognize the postgres node. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider a docker container to be a whole different computer, under normal circumstances it has no access to the host machine it runs on.

Update your docker-compose.yml to mount a volume on `/data` in the Node-RED container. This will ensure that both your flows and any nodes you install are persisted across a restart of the container. As it is if you restart the container you WILL loose your flow.

Then use the palette manager to install the postgres node into the running NR instance.